# Is SDL too low level for a beginner?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am getting started in game development. I started by learning SDL because it seems before I start developing big games, I have to start with the most basic stuff, like Tetris or Snake. I was wondering if SDL is too low-level. If I start with something as low level as SDL, will that make other high level libraries easier to pick up? Like for example, when someone is good with assembler, C seems easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The C++ and SDL combination is fairly low level, but not so much so that a beginner can't make good progress with it, and you can't really get much more 'high level' than SDL unless you use a premade engine.